# Keep user logged in when switching between apps

Tags: ios, swift

I have 2 apps which connects to the same database of users, this means that user uses the same account to log into both apps. I am interested if there is a way to let user log in only once, therefore the user will be already logged in the second app.

Comment: You can manage with isUserLoggedIn bool variable in the database. If user logged in change that bool value to true. Once user logged out change that to false. Based on that value, you can validate the user already logged in or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, Use API for user checklogin. And from server-end maintain the session for user login.

Now In app, call your checklogin API in `AppDidlaunch`. If your sever api param says User is already login then redirect the user to Home VC else redirect to Login VC.